# How can I import styling into Jupyter-Notebook using Matplotlib using plt.style.use?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have the following import which I am trying to use for styling but I keep receiving the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 3
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 3 plt.style.use('science', 'notebook','dark_background')

TypeError: use() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

I am using Macbook Pro ARM - not sure if that is the reason, but I have tried everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`matplotlib.style.use`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/style_api.html#matplotlib.style.use), the input to the method should be a *str, dict, Path or list*.

Your current input to the method however is neither of them. Thus, pass them as a list to the method: `plt.style.use(['science', 'notebook','dark_background'])`.